# Sum of random variable (advanced probability)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_k\}_{k\geq1}$ be nonnegative i.i.d. random variables, and $T_0 = 0$, $T_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. Let $\{Y_j\}_{j\geq 0}$ be another sequence of nonnegative i.i.d. random variables. The $\{X_k\}$ and $\{Y_j\}$ are defined on the same probability space, but their joint distribution is immaterial for this exercise. Let $D_n =T_n +Y_n$ for $n\geq 0$, and
$$N_t = \sum_{n \geq 0}1(T_n \leq t < D_n) \quad \text{for} \quad t\in [0,\infty).$$ $n≥0$.
Assuming that $EY_0 < EX_1$ < $\infty$, show that

$$P(N_t =0\quad \text{for some} \quad t>0)=1$$

The story that gives some meaning to this mathematical set-up. A park opens up at time $t = 0$ and the first visitor (visitor number $0$) arrives also at time $0$. After that visitor $n$ arrives to the park at time $T_n$. $Y_n$ is the amount of time that visitor $n$ lingers at the park, and $D_n$ is the moment visitor $n$ leaves the park. $N_t$ is the number of visitors at the park at time $t$. How to show that eventually there comes a point in time when the park is empty, assuming that the mean inter-arrival time is larger than the mean sojourn time.